# Activerecord dirty check for either created or updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a ActiveRecord model say List with has a connected boolean flag?

I want a callback to check if the List is reconnected which can happen 2 ways

- connected for the first time while created
- disconnected and reconnected with a update

I want to use ActiveMecord::Dirty api to do the check..but i wonder if there is a better way?

I come across this situation a lot and was wondering if there is a API which gives me changes as [nil, true] on create for changes to connected flag.

I use this for calling a 3rd party so need it after commit.

```
# The first line in the code checks if list is created with connected true and
# the second line checks if list was updated from connected false to true.

def reconnected?
  return true if connected_previous_change.blank? && connected

  connected_previous_change == [false, true]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite the callback as follows:

```
def reconnected?
  connected_previously_changed? && connected
end
```

`connected_previously_changed?` would return `true` when the `connected` attribute value was changed - Useful while checking in an after_commit callback. The change could be from `nil` to any value (`true`/`false`) and vice versa. This returns true even when the value changes from `false` to `true` and vice versa.
So we'd need the second condition to check if the current value is `true`.

Refer: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html

Comment: I need it after commit..

Comment: Oh my bad!! I didn't notice that you needed it in an after_commit. In that case, you could use `connected_previously_changed?` method. I'll modify my answer